# First time install of Laravel with Breeze inside Homestead - npm symlink issue with acorn

Tags: laravel, npm, symlink, homestead, laravel-breeze

I'm still new to Laravel and Homestead but have been working through all the Laracast tutorials with no problems in the past couple of weeks.

Now we've come to starting a brand new project using `laravel/breeze` instead of doing all the authentication by hand.

I'm using Homestead 13.3.2 and Vagrant 2.3.3 on a Windows 10 machine.

The error occurs when I run the install command:

`php artisan breeze:install`

```
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../acorn/bin/acorn
npm ERR! dest /home/vagrant/Code/flashcards/node_modules/.bin/acorn
npm ERR! errno -71
npm ERR! EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../acorn/bin/acorn' -> '/home/vagrant/Code/flashcards/node_modules/.bin/acorn'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2022-12-30T14_42_25_106Z-debug-0.log

   INFO  Breeze scaffolding installed successfully.
```

I'm running node v14.20.0 npm 8.16.0.

the slightly more verbose error from the log says

```
08 verbose stack Error: EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../acorn/bin/acorn' -> '/home/vagrant/Code/flashcards/node_modules/.bin/acorn'
709 verbose cwd /home/vagrant/Code/flashcards
710 verbose Linux 5.4.0-124-generic
711 verbose node v14.20.0
712 verbose npm  v8.16.0
713 error code EPROTO
714 error syscall symlink
715 error path ../acorn/bin/acorn
716 error dest /home/vagrant/Code/flashcards/node_modules/.bin/acorn
717 error errno -71
718 error EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../acorn/bin/acorn' -> '/home/vagrant/Code/flashcards/node_modules/.bin/acorn'
719 verbose exit -71
```

Comment: npm and windows is always a pain. As soon as you have to do npm install, do this: `npm install --no-bin-links` , it will prevent making those symlinks

Comment: Thanks @UnderDog. Problem is that I’m not running it manually it’s part of the breeze install.